# Обновление Python с 3.5 до 3.6 на Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, установка, python-3.5

У меня на компьютере установлен python 3.5 и мне нужно обновить его до 3.6. Насколько я понимаю, если я просто скачаю новую версию и установлю мне придётся заново устанавливать библиотеки и все такое. 
Есть ли какой-то способ обновить пайтон на виндовс? Через консоль мб

Comment: не придется. инсталлятор достаточно умен чтобы просто обновить нужное.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Просто поставьте новую версию, используя [стандартный установщик](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

> если я просто скачаю новую версию и установлю мне придётся заново устанавливать библиотеки и все такое.

```
c:\> py -3.5 -m pip freeze >requirements.txt
c:\> py -3.6 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```